# Yii-2 how to sum up the values of an object returned from json?

Tags: json, yii2, sum, yii2-advanced-app

I have a `json` response. In the response, I have an object named `xhqd`. Now, I want to add all these values. Below is my `json`

```
{
"details": [
    {
        "zdjh": "002999001180",
        "sjsj": "2018-07-03T16:39:46",
        "xhqd": "15",
        "i": 0
    },
    {
        "zdjh": "002999001180",
        "sjsj": "2018-07-03T16:41:48",
        "xhqd": "18",
        "i": 1
    },
    {
        "zdjh": "002999001180",
        "sjsj": "2018-07-03T16:43:50",
        "xhqd": "18",
        "i": 2
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    {
        "zdjh": "002999001180",
        "sjsj": "2018-07-03T17:06:07",
        "xhqd": "19",
        "i": 13
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do `15+18+18+....+19` in `Yii2`?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Atleast input your code that you have tried, which shows you have added some input and hardwork. Please checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii has a helper class [Json](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-json) it contains a method Json::decode use it to decode the json string.

Dont forget to add namespace `use yii\helpers\Json;`

```
$jsonData = '{
"details": [
    {
        "zdjh": "002999001180",
        "sjsj": "2018-07-03T16:39:46",
        "xhqd": "15",
        "i": 0
    },
    {
        "zdjh": "002999001180",
        "sjsj": "2018-07-03T16:41:48",
        "xhqd": "18",
        "i": 1
    },
    {
        "zdjh": "002999001180",
        "sjsj": "2018-07-03T16:43:50",
        "xhqd": "18",
        "i": 2
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    {
        "zdjh": "002999001180",
        "sjsj": "2018-07-03T17:06:07",
        "xhqd": "19",
        "i": 13
    }
  ]
}';

$json_decode =  Json::decode($jsonData);
$total = 0;
foreach($json_decode as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $valuesKey => $valdata){
         $total += $valdata->xhqd;
    }
}

echo $total;
```

Comment: Welcome @MrFaisal. :-). Next time just note to also input  some sort of code from you side which relates to R&D of your work

Comment: Next time I'll share it also